# javascript json data script fails to work

Tags: javascript, json

Is this correct json? Why doesn't it display in #id ? I got similar code from https://www.sitepoint.com/colors-json-example/ -copied it and replaced my own values but it doesn't work. Anybody explain this?

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
{
 "standing": [

{"code" : "G", "rank" : "1"},
{"code" : "I", "rank" : "2"},
{"code" : "M", "rank" : "3"},
{"code" : "X", "rank" : "4"},
{"code" : "A", "rank" : "5"},
{"code" : "B", "rank" : "6"},
{"code" : "C", "rank" : "7"},
{"code" : "D", "rank" : "8"},
{"code" : "E", "rank" : "9"}

]
}   

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
standing.code + " " + standing.rank;
</script>
```

Comment: That's not JSON, that's an Object literal. In order to use it, you need to store it in a variable. `var standing = [ ... ];`. Note that standing is an array, so you need `standing[0].code` and `standing[0].rank`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you want to achieve here but the following script might help you: just replace the 0 to get another letter or make a for loop to get all the letters.

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var standing = [
{"code" : "G", "rank" : "1"},
{"code" : "I", "rank" : "2"},
{"code" : "M", "rank" : "3"},
{"code" : "X", "rank" : "4"},
{"code" : "A", "rank" : "5"},
//etc
];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = standing[0].code + " " + standing[0].rank;
</script>
```

Why your code wasn't working:

- you needed to assign your array to a variable
- you didn't specified which index you wanted to display

Answer (score 1):

You haven't assigned the object to a variable. You need to do that in order to reference it later:

```
<script>
var standing =  [

 {"code" : "G", "rank" : "1"},
 {"code" : "I", "rank" : "2"},
 {"code" : "M", "rank" : "3"},
 // etc/
]

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
standing[0].code + " " + standing[0].rank;
</script>
```

Now `standing` is an array of objects that you can access with `standing[index]`.

Comment: I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

"standing" is an array which contains objects. you can access first one as `standing[0].code`
hope it helps.

Comment: You missed the deeper problem. `standing` isn't accessible.